# Seen pronounced 'sin'

Tags: british-english

My other half is from West Sussex in England. Herself and her sister both pronounce seen as 'sin' and some of her friends from the area she grew up in pronounce it in the same way (including her mother).

A former colleague of mine who was originally from Brighton also pronounced it this way and recently I saw someone on the TV from Surrey pronounce it like this also.

Is there a specific reason for this? Teaching? Dialect?

I found online that the Suffolk and Essex dialects are known for this but found nothing relating to Sussex/Surrey.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffolk_dialect#Mutations_to_certain_words
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essex_dialect#Pronunciation

Comment: It's definitely Sussex dialect. I know clergy who are Sussex born and bred who have this peculiarity; sentences with both *seen* and *sin* are odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a [dialectal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essex_dialect) pronunciation of   [ɪ] instead of [iː] :

Essex dialect:

> - The shortening of certain elongated vowel sounds from [iː] to [ɪ], e.g. been > ‘bin’, seen > ‘sin’

[Sussex dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sussex_dialect):

> - /iː/ is pronounced as /ɪ/ in such words as sheep, week, or field

(Wikipedia)

Comment: Doesn't *everyone* pronounce been as 'bin', unless they want to stress the word?

Comment: @TusharRaj - yes, "beach" might need more attention :)

Comment: Lol. Personally, I've always wondered why we can't use perfectly innocent words like `beach` and `sheet` as minced oaths. Better than inventing a new one. And considerably more deniability :)

Comment: @TusharRaj: No. /biːn/ also exists, and for some people is the general pronunciation; particularly I believe in British English.

Comment: @sumelic: Huh. I hadn't noticed. Haven't watched many British movies, and I'd be lying if I said I had their pronunciation figured out :)